# Enviar documentos a una carpeta en específico

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo una descarga de documentos de una ubicación a mi máquina pero al momento de realizarla esta se hace a la carpeta en donde se encuentra mi código.

Lo que deseo es poder *asignarle una ruta* para que no se vaya a donde esta el código.

Ocupo lo siguiente:

```
import urllib.request
ruta =("http://" + xxxxxxxxxxxxx)
urllib.request.urlcleanup()
request = urllib.request.urlretrieve(ruta,nombreDoc)
```

Se que en la ultima línea es donde tengo que ingresar la ruta a donde quiero que se vayan los documentos pero no se en que posición deba de ir.

Comment: ¿Que tipo de documento vas a descargar? Una pagina html? un documento binario?

Comment: son XML pero esos ya los descargo con el codigo de arriba, de hecho descargo cualquier tipo de documento lo unico que me hace falta es direccionar la descarga a una ubicacion. digamos que las quiero mandar a C:\Nuevo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar algo como esto:

```
>>> import os
>>> import urllib.request
>>> url = 'https://www.martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf'
>>> archivo = os.path.basename(url) # spec.pdf
>>> carpeta = 'C:%sNuevo' % os.sep # C:\Nuevo
>>> ruta_destino = os.path.join(carpeta, archivo) # C:\Nuevo\spec.pdf
>>> urllib.request.urlretrieve(ruta, ruta_destino)
```

Estoy usando `os.sep` ya que no estoy seguro de como hacer la unión de las rutas en Windows. Imagino que usando `os.sep` debería funcionar ya que retorna el separador de las rutas de acuerdo al sistema operativo bajo el que Python está corriendo.

Comment: Hola Me sirvio perfecto, muchisimas gracias!!!!